# How to import modules from SVN in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio.

In my Eclipse's workspace I have the following structure:

- MyApp (pointing to SVN repo 1)
- Library B (pointing to SVN repo 2)
- Library C (pointing to SVN repo 3)

When I import it to AndroidStudio it creates a single project with 3 modules:

- App
- LibraryB
- LibraryC

LibraryB and LibraryC are used in multiple projects so I need to commit them in a separate SVN and include it in MyApp as a svn:external.

Those are the steps I'm trying with but I think I'm doing it wrong:

- Select the whole project: **VCS->Enable Version Control Integration -> Subversion**
- **Right-click LibraryB -> Subversion -> Share Directory**, select the SVN location for the module, and then **Right-click LibraryB -> Subversion -> Commit Directory** excluding the build folder.

At this point the module is in the SVN repo so I try to import it to a new project. I create a new project.

How can I checkout the module to the new project, allowing to commit changes in the module to the module's SVN?

I have tried:

- At the new project I create a folder named libraryB and  then bring the module files with **VCS->Checkout From Version Control**. At this point I'm prompted with `You have checked out an Android Studio project file  C:/path/to/Project/libraryB/build.gradle` I press No and then try. Project Structure-> + Module-> Import Existing Project (as a module) -> select the path `C:/path/to/Project/libraryB` but the wizard shows an error `Select modules to import`
- Setup the SVN configuration in the new project, then **right-click->Subversion-> Create external**. With the checkbox checkout enabled select the svn path and the local folder. The files are retrieved but not as a module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On checking out the project, Create a new module with the same name of your modules.

copy your main folder and also the build.gradle to the new module.

Right click on the module> subversion> Share Directory.
Point the svn location where you want to share your module.